# Parameters for Django REST Model Model.objects.create function

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Need to know the parameters for Model.objects.create function. This example is from this link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships. Here in this line Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)

What is `album=album`? I think right side assigned value of album is `Album.objects.create(**validated_data)` but what is the left side album. As per the documentation it is the Model field. But neither Model `Track` and `Album contains field`album`.

Is this the default model name for `Album`?

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tracks_data = validated_data.pop('tracks')
        album = Album.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for track_data in tracks_data:
            Track.objects.create(album=album, **track_data)
        return album
```

Answer (score 0):

Not explicitly said in the tutorial, but it's assumed that there is a ForeignKey field in `Track` called album, that refers to the `Album` model.

Notice the following in the second code snippet within the Example section:

```
>>> album = Album.objects.create(album_name="The Grey Album", artist='Danger Mouse')
>>> Track.objects.create(album=album, order=1, title='Public Service Announcement', duration=245)
<Track: Track object>
```

That hints what I'm saying. The fact that there is no field `album`on `TrackSerializer` would have raise an error if it was simply `Track.objects.create(**track_data)` because the field `album` would be missing. Thus, you need to include it explicitly.